# ';' expected in after if

Tags: java, if-statement

I get this strange errors:

```
Ex2.java:8: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <= 15.0){
                          ^
Ex2.java:11: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <= 19.0)
                          ^
Ex2.java:15: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <= 25.0)
                          ^
Ex2.java:19: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <= 30.0)
                          ^
Ex2.java:23: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <=40.0)
                         ^
Ex2.java:27: error: ';' expected
          If (IMC <=90.0)
```

I asked some of my friends and they have no idea why this is happening
here, take my code.

```
public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double peso = 80;
        double altura = 1.88;
        double IMC = (peso / (altura * altura));
        System.out.print("IMC:");
        System.out.println(IMC);
        If (IMC &lt;= 15.0){
            System.out.println ("Muito abaixo do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC &lt;= 19.0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Abaixo do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC &lt;= 25.0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Peso Normal");
        }
        If (IMC &lt;= 30.0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Acima do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC &lt;=40.0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Obeso");
        }
        If (IMC &lt;=90.0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Muito Obeso");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your indent and placement of brackets, and this won't be a problem.

Comment: @Tobb While fixing the indentation should be done, it is not the cause of this problem.

Comment: Also, this code will print all the labels if IMC is 15 or less.  I think you want to be using 'else if' instead of simply 'if'.

Comment: 'If' is not 'if' , it isn't a strange error!

Comment: @unholysampler I am aware, but in any case it's completely impossible to understand that code the way that it's formatted. Even if `if` was spelled correctly, it would still be hell to figure out where a missing symbol was..

Answer (score 9):

Java is Highly CASE Sensitive and it's `if` and NOT `If`

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how this looks with proper indentation:

```
public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double peso = 80;
        double altura = 1.88;
        double IMC = (peso / (altura * altura));
        System.out.print("IMC:");
        System.out.println(IMC);
        If (IMC <= 15.0) {
            System.out.println ("Muito abaixo do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC <= 19.0) {
            System.out.println ("Abaixo do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC <= 25.0) {
            System.out.println ("Peso Normal");
        }
        If (IMC <= 30.0) {
            System.out.println ("Acima do peso ideal");
        }
        If (IMC <= 40.0) {
            System.out.println ("Obeso");
        }
        If (IMC <= 90.0) {
            System.out.println ("Muito Obeso");
        }
    }
}
```

No problems here, other than the fact that the `if` control-structure in Java is written with a lowercase `i`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Java lexical parser does not recognize "If" as a keyword, and treats it as a function symbol. Then it expects a ; after the (...).

You probably want the keyword "if" with lowercase i.